# Iterating with foreach loop and deleting each of the mail list elements (with lambda expression in Java 8 )

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java-8

I have couple of below questions please. I 'veused a For loop to iterate mails in an inbox and then delete each of the mail list elements but

1. The below 'for' loop works for the first mail and then either elementnotvisible exception  or timeoutexeption are occuring. (used explicit waits with expected conditions but somehow not working )
2. Can this be achieved by foreach loop using lambda (- > ) expression , if so can anyone please show me here ?

Here is my code block.

```
      List<WebElement> mailList =   driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".all_message-min_text"));

       mailList.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));

       //==============================================================================================================

       //Select all approach with for loop
       for(int i=0;i<mailList.size();i++) 

       {
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("i[id^='checkoff']")));
       System.out.println("Selecting the email on view : "+ i );
       driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i[id^='checkoff']")).click();
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(".fa-trash")));
       driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".fa-trash")).click();
       System.out.println("Deleted email number "+i + " " +"frm the Inbox of 'emailuser'");

       }
       System.out.println("Deleted all the emails from the Inbox of 'emailuser'");  


       driver.quit();
```

thanks in advance,

================================                                             Here is the html source with the 3 resulting locators

```
            <div class="all_message-min">
            <div id="check_1513617894-100031086054-emailuser" class="all_message-min-check-container" onclick="checkBox('1513617894-100031086054-emailuser');if(event.stopPropagation){event.stopPropagation();}event.cancelBubble=true;">
            <i id="checkon_1513617894-100031086054-emailuser" class="fa fa-check-square fa-lg" style="display:none;color#aaa;"/>
            <i id="checkoff_1513617894-100031086054-emailuser" class="fa fa-square-o fa-lg" style="color:#aaa;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="all_message-min_autor ng-binding" style="display:none" title="TO"/>
            <div class="all_message-min_autor ng-binding" title="FROM">True Nijam</div>
            <div class="all_message-min_text all_message-min_text-3">Third email</div>
            <div class="all_message-min_datte all_message-min_datte-3 ng-binding">moments ago</div>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li id="row_1513617880-100031085862-emailuser" class="all_message-item all_message-item-parent cf ng-scope" ng-repeat="email in emails" onclick="showTheMessage('1513617880-100031085862-emailuser');">
            <div class="all_message-min">
            <div id="check_1513617880-100031085862-emailuser" class="all_message-min-check-container" onclick="checkBox('1513617880-100031085862-emailuser');if(event.stopPropagation){event.stopPropagation();}event.cancelBubble=true;">
            <i id="checkon_1513617880-100031085862-emailuser" class="fa fa-check-square fa-lg" style="display:none;color#aaa;"/>
            <i id="checkoff_1513617880-100031085862-emailuser" class="fa fa-square-o fa-lg" style="color:#aaa;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="all_message-min_autor ng-binding" style="display:none" title="TO"/>
            <div class="all_message-min_autor ng-binding" title="FROM">True Nijam</div>
            <div class="all_message-min_text all_message-min_text-3">Second mail</div>
            <div class="all_message-min_datte all_message-min_datte-3 ng-binding">moments ago</div>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li id="row_1513611712-100030966494-emailuser" class="all_message-item all_message-item-parent cf ng-scope" ng-repeat="email in emails" onclick="showTheMessage('1513611712-100030966494-emailuser');">
            <div class="all_message-min">
            <div id="check_1513611712-100030966494-emailuser" class="all_message-min-check-container" onclick="checkBox('1513611712-100030966494-emailuser');if(event.stopPropagation){event.stopPropagation();}event.cancelBubble=true;">
            <i id="checkon_1513611712-100030966494-emailuser" class="fa fa-check-square fa-lg" style="display:none;color#aaa;"/>
            <i id="checkoff_1513611712-100030966494-emailuser" class="fa fa-square-o fa-lg" style="color:#aaa;"/>
            </div>
```

Comment: Which line gives exception on second iteration? Also no need to find element again, the EC in both cases returns the element if it is able to satisfy the condition. Add the html source.

Comment: Added above the html source with the 3 resulting locators, can any one please answer any of my questions here. thanks..

Comment: Got it working with a page refresh at the end of the loop in each iteration. driver.navigate().refresh(); But still I am curious to know how it can be achieved using a foreach() loop, which I believe can be short and sweet.